# cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment (Xamarin C#)

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I try to do `DrawerLayout`

But I facing issue

```
Java.Lang.ClassCastException: tieit.droid.MyListFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Here is my code in MainViewModel code:

```
  using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TieiT.Core
{
    public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        readonly Type[] _menuItemTypes = {
            typeof(MyListViewModel),
            typeof(MySettingsViewModel),
        };

        public IEnumerable<string> MenuItems { get; private set; } = new [] { "My List", "My Settings" };

        public void ShowDefaultMenuItem()
        {
            NavigateTo (0);
        }

        public void NavigateTo (int position)
        {
            ShowViewModel (_menuItemTypes [position]);
        }
    }

    public class MenuItem : Tuple<string, Type>
    {
        public MenuItem (string displayName, Type viewModelType)
            : base (displayName, viewModelType)
        {}

        public string DisplayName
        {
            get { return Item1; }
        }

        public Type ViewModelType
        {
            get { return Item2; }
        }
    }
}
```

When I have error, it hightlights this:

```
public void NavigateTo (int position)
    {
        ShowViewModel (_menuItemTypes [position]);
    }
```

Here is MyListFragment:

```
   using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;

using MvvmCross.Droid.Shared.Attributes;
using MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging.Fragments;


using TieiT.Core;

namespace TieiT.Droid
{
    [MvxFragmentAttribute(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.frameLayout)]
    [Register("tieit.droid.MyListFragment")]
    public class MyListFragment : MvxFragment<MyListViewModel>
    {
        public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyListView, container, false);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my activity where I need to show `DrawerLayout`:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat;
using TieiT.Droid;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
using Toolbar = Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
using Fragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;

using TieiT.Core;

namespace TieiT.Droid.Views
{
    [Activity]
    public class GeneralInfo : MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity<MainViewModel>
    {

        ActionBarDrawerToggle _drawerToggle;

        ListView _drawerListView;

        DrawerLayout _drawerLayout;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.GeneralInfoPage);
            var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
           SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

            _drawerListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.drawerListView);
            _drawerListView.ItemClick += (s, e) => ShowFragmentAt(e.Position);
            _drawerListView.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, global::Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, ViewModel.MenuItems.ToArray());

            _drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawerLayout);

            _drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, _drawerLayout, Resource.String.OpenDrawerString, Resource.String.CloseDrawerString);

            _drawerLayout.SetDrawerListener(_drawerToggle);

            ShowFragmentAt(0);
        }

        void ShowFragmentAt(int position)
        {
            ViewModel.NavigateTo(position);

            Title = ViewModel.MenuItems.ElementAt(position);

            _drawerLayout.CloseDrawer(_drawerListView);
        }

        protected override void OnPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            _drawerToggle.SyncState();

            base.OnPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            if (_drawerToggle.OnOptionsItemSelected(item))
                return true;

            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

How I can fix this error?

Thank's for help.

***UPDATE***

My Main Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- content must go before menu because of z-order -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
<!-- menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerListView"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here is what i have in console:

```
    [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.Lang.ClassCastException: tieit.droid.MyListFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
10-01 19:52:15.838 E/mono-rt ( 3039):   --- End of managed Java.Lang.ClassCastException stack trace ---
10-01 19:52:15.838 E/mono-rt ( 3039): java.lang.ClassCastException: tieit.droid.MyListFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Comment: Please add your layout xml and the stacktrace to the question.

Comment: Updated post @StefanWanitzek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed wrong packed, becouse the `MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging` support only `Fragment` and you get error when you try cast it. When using `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` you should install the `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging` and `'MvvmCross.Droid.V7.AppCompat'`.